# how to hide/show status bar

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I want to show/hide status bar outside activity.

My code is below:

```
activity.getWindow().getDecorView()
    .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
```

It doesn't work for me. `activity.getWindow()` returns null.

Answer (score 2):

> Using Immersive Full-Screen Mode

HIDE / SHOW - In your Activity

```
// Hide status bar
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

// Show status bar
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

More [Post](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: what do u mean by **outside activity**, where u using this ?

Comment: I dont implement native android programming. So I use activity.getWindow(); And it returns null.

Comment: I mean to say, where u actually using it may be u can get context of that activity where u can use it.

Comment: post that button function with whole java code, that can be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
        (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
            // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        } else {
            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
            // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
            // other navigational controls.
        }
    }
});
```

Refer this link for more details.

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html